# mis-matched output from unique() and nlevels()

Tags: r, unique, r-factor

In an attempt to run an `lm()`, R returned an error from having factors with less than 2-levels.  Below is a short table that lists the Type, and 3-measures of 'levels'.

Why would `length(unique(x[,i]))` not provide the same output as `nlevels(x[,i])`?

[image: levels]

Comment: you can have more levels than unique values... see `x = factor(c("a", "b"), levels=c("a", "b", "c"))` . One way this can happen is by subsetting your data.. example. `d1 = data.frame(x=letters[1:4]) ; d2 = d1[d1$x %in% c("a", "b"), , drop=FALSE ] ; str(d2$x)` . `droplevels` is a useful function

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is that `NA` is counted as unique value, but not a level in a factor:

```
> a <- as.factor(c("A","B","A",NA))
> unique(a)
[1] A    B    <NA>
Levels: A B
> length(unique(a))
[1] 3
> levels(a)
[1] "A" "B"
> nlevels(a)
[1] 2
```

Comment: This is a valuable hint, but would only count toward recognizing 1-level.  In my 4th factor from the top, I have 10 unique values and nlevels=0.

Comment: @braxtonlewis, you may notice that those `nlevels()=0` records are all for integer or numerics.  This because `unique` can be applied to all types, but `nlevels` can only applied to `factor`.

Comment: *Strictly* speaking nlevels() can be applied to non-factors also `x <- 1:4; attr(x, "levels") <- c("a", "b"); nlevels(x); class(x)`